# Finding a specific surface integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Calculate

$$ \iint_S Z ds $$

where $S$ is the surface whose sides $S_1$ are given by cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$, whose bottom $S_2$ is the disk $x^2+y^2$ is less than or equal to $1$ in the plane $z=0$, and whose top $S_3$ is the portion of the plane $z=x+1$ inside the cylinder.

I am not sure how to do this problem at all. I can somewhat visualize it, but I don't know how to proceed with this problem. How do I calculate this?

Comment: You should clarify what is the integral: (Z)ds?

Comment: @gimusi that's all the problem gives. any clue?

Comment: First, I would draw a picture to help organize your thoughts. Are you finding the combined surface area ?

Comment: @MathWannaBe Use example #4 of this website to help: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx